# Is there a way to have python automatically look through some text I had it print out in the terminal for a keyword in that text?

Tags: python, terminal, automation

Lets say I have python print out a paragraph of words in the terminal. Is there a way for me to have that same python program look through the paragraph it just printed for a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to find your keyword(s), try regex to match patterns.

Comment: There's nuance to his question though: 'How do I search through text that has already been printed.'

Comment: @DanielScott Could you explain nuance? I havent really used that word in my life, so its a bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are a few ways to look for text in a larger string.

The easiest is the `in` keyword, but it is case sensitive. You'd have to preprocess the string to lowercase it, or remove punctuation, if you'd need that functionality:

```
>>> print('flarp' in 'this is sentence with flarp in it')
True
```

There is also regex, which is not Python specific, and instead a standard implemented across many languages. It is not straightforward.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'flarp', 'this is sentence with flarp in it')
['flarp']
```

documentation for string methods, some of which might help you (like `startswith` or `index`): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#string-methods

documentation for regex in Python. But as they say, "you want to solve a problem with regex? Now you have two problems": https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

===

If you want to read the terminal output of your program, why not read the actual data that your program is reading out? You presumably already have that data available to parse, otherwise how would you have printed it? This will be much more straightforward than reading a file.